# Maven : Facing issue is creating the google Endpoint Liberary

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Getting Error At the time of running the

mvn appengine:endpoints_get_client_lib

I got their are some issue with the maven plugin  but how can i solve them. 
 error Log is given below.

```
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
  [INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building claritus-travelaware 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.42:endpoints_get_client_lib (default-cli) @ claritus-travelaware ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] Google App Engine Java SDK - Generate endpoints get client lib
[INFO] Using Class Name:com.claritus.travelaware.endpoint.UserLocationEP
[INFO] Using Class Name:com.claritus.travelaware.endpoint.SubscribeUserEP
[INFO] Using Class Name:com.claritus.travelaware.YourFirstAPI
[INFO] Executing endpoints Command=[get-client-lib, -cp, /home/claritus/Desktop/workspace/claritus-travelaware/target/claritus-travelaware-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes:/home/claritus/Desktop/workspace/claritus-travelaware/target/classes:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.9.42/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.42.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-endpoints/1.9.42/appengine-endpoints-1.9.42.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.31/mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.0.Final/hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.0.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.15.0-GA/javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/claritus/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, -o, /home/claritus/Desktop/workspace/claritus-travelaware/target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF, -w, /home/claritus/Desktop/workspace/claritus-travelaware/target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints, -l, java, -bs, maven, com.claritus.travelaware.endpoint.UserLocationEP, com.claritus.travelaware.endpoint.SubscribeUserEP, com.claritus.travelaware.YourFirstAPI]
API client library written to /home/claritus/Desktop/workspace/claritus-travelaware/target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/userLocation-v1-java.zip
API client library written to /home/claritus/Desktop/workspace/claritus-travelaware/target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/subscribeUsers-v1-java.zip
API client library written to /home/claritus/Desktop/workspace/claritus-travelaware/target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/firstApi-v1-java.zip
[INFO] BUILDING Endpoints Client Library from: /home/claritus/Desktop/workspace/claritus-travelaware/target/endpoints-client-libs/firstApi/pom.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.227 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-16T10:07:40+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/170M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.42:endpoints_get_client_lib (default-cli) on project claritus-travelaware: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.42:endpoints_get_client_lib failed: ${maven.home} is not specified as a directory: '/home/claritus/Desktop/workspace/claritus-travelaware/EMBEDDED'. -> [Help 1]`**

```
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```